# How to avoid creating 'defer'red observable when it is 'concat'ed to enumeration?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

When executing the following code,

```
var o = Rx.Observable.interval(100).flatMap(n =>
    Rx.Observable.concat(
            Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3]),
            Rx.Observable.defer(()=> {
                        console.log("defer");
                        return Rx.Observable.from[4,5,6];
})));
o.take(1).subscribe(n => console.log(n), e => console.log(e), ()=>console.log("complete"));
```

I get the output.

```
1
complete
deferred
```

It may cost a bit to create a deferred observable, but the Observable.from() runs and completes, which causes the deferred observable created even though I limit the stream with take(1). (This snippet comes from the REST API client which requests the next page continuously.)

How to avoid creating deferred observable when I need to `concat`ed it to enumeration?